# Cognos, amount multipled after join

Tags: sql, frameworks, cognos

I have two tables:

- Application table with columns `applicationNO`, `loanAmount`, `product`
- Collateral table with columns `applicationNo`, `propertyType`, `collateralValue`

I did a join at Database view level for these two tables then published as a package in a single query as following:

```
applicationNo, loanAmount, product, propertyType, collateralValue
```

as a result, my `loanAmount` will be multiplied IF there is multiple property for the application.

How should I handle this in Framework Manager so that the value will be correct in cube and reports?

Comment: This is an SQL problem.   Resolving the data issues in the underlying view would be best, but there are some work-arounds within Cognos when working with aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your loanAmount field in Report Studio, set the Property 'Aggregate Function' to minimum, maximum, or average.  This will stop it from summarizing.

You are going to have problems with Rollup Aggregate if you are summarizing on ApplicationNo.

Your ideal reporting facts are going to have Fact data at a single level.  In this case you have two fact columns which are on two seperate levels.  Loan amount at the applicationNo level, and collateralValue at the ApplicationNo,propertyType level.  If you create a report with Total/Subtotal lines, you are going to need to either Throw out the Product type or throw out the Loan Amount in order to get accurate totals.